# Why do I hear random "creepy" noises in minecraft NOT in a cave?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I hear really creepy noises even on super flat landscape.

Does it mean Herobrine is near me?

Comment: Maybe Herobrine is nearby.

Answer (score 14):

In addition to sounds corresponding to animals and monsters (collectively referred to as mobs) the game also plays music and the occasional random 'teaser' sound clips or ambiance. It is simply meant to be background in the game to put you off your feet.

They occur most often in caves, but the game doesn't actually know if you are in a cave or not. Rather, the game uses light levels to determine when to play some of those sounds. The area checked isn't always immediately in front of you, either. Depending on your flat world, the game doesn't have actual caves, but may be detecting a void. The game looks for spaces with light levels below 8 regardless of where you are.

If what you are hearing is not a mob sound, it's probably safe to ignore it.

Here is a clip of some of the sounds to ignore:

If you are playing on a multiplayer server or single player server with another person, if anybody summons a wither then everybody will hear it as local sound. The same is true for killing the enderdragon.

If you are in the Nether, as a little bonus, ghasts can be heard as nearby/local even if there are none within any nearby chunks. The game only checks that a ghast has spawned somewhere in the Nether (could even be hundreds of chunks away) and plays the sound for anybody in the Nether.

And seriously, there is no, have never been and never will be a herobrine.

- https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ambience

Answer (score 0):

The game actually trys to help you find caves. It does this in two ways, one of which is the bats. They spawn in dark areas and squeak.. forever...

The other way is what is called '[Ambiance](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ambience)' but is more commonly referred to as the 'Cave' sounds. Minecraft will randomly play one of a few sounds it has (they are meant to sound ominous) if it can find an open air area near you that has no light levels within it. All that matters for this to happen is for it to randomly decide to check for a dark cave, and if it finds one to play the noise.

I shall assume the reference to the on running joke that is [Herobrine](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Herobrine), as just a reference to the on running joke of Herobrine.

Comment: I had to make a correction, but for your sake I'd like to correct you. It doesn't look for caves. Nor does it have to be 0 light. It only needs to find a  space with light level below 8, this can occur at night anyway, for example. The spawn rules for bats are almost the same, they only need a valid spawning space, and a proper block as well as light levels below 8. ALthought these things typically happen in caves, the OP mentions being on Superflat, which has no caves (unless modifed).

Comment: @ydobonebi Hey if putting my info into your answer gets a more complete answer then so be it. You just originally had it being all random instead of denoting it is a very specific and well known use case for it to happen. Cheers :)

Comment: actually, your information was incorrect, but it lead me to look it up and verify my own information which I then corrected  I didn't use your info at all (because it's wrong and still is). The only similarity was the term 'ambience' which I already knew that was the term, just decided to use a more laymen term. And the occurrence IS RANDOM. You give a scenario, that yes, will trigger the event. But is only an edge case for the trigger. The game randomly checks for spaces and if it detects light under level 8 then will (randomly) play a sound at that spot (upto 20 blocks away)

Comment: and to quote the the wiki `nor does the player need to be underground to hear it.`

Comment: @ydobonebi Haha, you are very amusing.. Come to chat if you want to try and explain to me how me saying 'All that matters for this to happen is for it to randomly decide to check for a dark cave, and if it finds one to play the noise.' is wrong but is exactly what you have also just said.

Comment: I was refering to the `that has no light levels within it` There is a difference between no light level and a light level less than 8. If a person takes that information and decides they never want to hear it (besides the obvious choice to turn the sounds off) and light areas up, they may believe they shouldn't hear them anymore, but if a block has light of 7, it could still generate the sound. My intent was that we can both have the correct information and I was hoping you would update that.

Comment: Also, it doesn't need to be a cave at all, even a dark forest can cause it.